# Final Topology and Subsets?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\emptyset \neq X_1,\dots,X_n\subseteq X$ and equip each $X_i$ with a topology $\tau^i$.  Then, is the topology generated by $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \tau^i$ on $\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ equal to the 
the final topology making the inclusions $X_i\to \bigcup_{i=1}^n X_i$ continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in general.

Let $X_1=[0,1]$ with the discrete topology and $X_2=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology. The set $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ is open in topology on $\Bbb R$ generated by these topologies on $X_1$ and $X_2$ but not in the final topology generated by the inclusions. The former makes the space the discrete union of $(\leftarrow,0)$ with the usual topology, $[0,1]$ with the discrete topology, and $(0,\to)$ with the usual topology; the latter is just the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Is this always true then?  I mean:  In general, if $X_1\subset X_2$ and $\tau^1$ is finer than $\tau^2|_{X_1}$ then is the topology generated by $\tau^1 \cup \tau^2$ equal to the disjoint union topology on $X_1 \sqcup X_2-X_1$?

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block: If I had taken $X_1$ to be $(0,1)$ with the discrete topology, every open nbhd of $0$ would still have to contain points of $(0,1)$ in the generated topology, so $0$ would still be in the closure of $(0,1)$, and you couldn’t break off $(\leftarrow,0]$ as a clopen piece.

Comment: Right, so in general you need $X_1$ to somehow be closed in $X_2$ (as a subset) then?

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block: That should work, yes.

Comment: I've been thinking about this topology, say $D$ is dense in $\tau^2$ but not in $\tau^1$ (in the case say $X_1$ is open) then I guess it isn't dense in $\tau_1\cup\tau_2$?

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block: Yes, as in the case of $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ in my example.